What is the correct way to configure nginx with vanilla JS for SPA
guys! I am doing a SPA using vanilla javascript and came across a problem. So ideally I want my nginx server to send me my index.html file whatever the URI user puts in the browser url box. And it works, however when the browser gets the index.html file, it obviously tries to fetch the rest of the files that are used by the html file, like images, css files and js scripts, but it fails to do that cause it cannot find it if the URI is a random string xD
So, I wonder how it is supposed to be fixed "the right way".
Here are my files:
nginx.conf:
http {
    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        root /app;
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }
}


events {}

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Transcendence</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <a href="/" class="nav_link" data-link>Profile</a>
        <a href="/game" class="nav_link" data-link>Game</a>
        <a href="/chat" class="nav_link" data-link>Chat</a>
    </nav>
    <script defer type="module" src="src/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Dockerfile
FROM nginx:1.24-bullseye

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /app

COPY index.html .

COPY ./src ./src

directory tree
directory tree

That configuration looks okay at a first glance; where does the "random string" come from?  If you look in your browser's debug tools, what's a sample URL that's failing?

You reference the script with a relative url.
<script defer type="module" src="src/js/index.js"></script>

Which means that if you query your page with a subpath (which you mentioned with the "random string"), it tries to load src/js/index.js relative to it.
So for example if you request http://localhost:8080/some-path it tries to load the index.js from http://localhost:8080/some-path/src/js/index.js, which fails. You should be able to verify that via your browers dev tools. It works, as you observed for http://localhost:8080/ because the relative path then resolves to http://localhost:8080/src/js/index.js where it actually can be found.
There are mainly 2 ways to fix the issue:

Use an absolute path for your static assets /src/js/index.js

Provide a base tag:
Definition and Usage
The <base> tag specifies the base URL and/or target for all relative URLs in a document.

Put the base tag in the head of your index.html:
<base href="/">

Just be aware that this also affects all relative links, image paths, etc. but usually that's also anyway what you want.


Personally I would suggest to use the second approach, which is "the right way" in most cases. However, there are some rare cases, where it does not fit, so I wanted to also mention the first approach.

I didn't know about the base HTML tag, very interesting. I share here the MDZ documentation for it. Just to note that, the base tag must be before any other tag that use URLs, so the best approach would be to put it before any <link> or <script> tag.
